# My iMac won't boot. Every time, no matter what mode I try booting in, it boots and stays on a blank white screen

Tags: imac, startup

I have a problem with my iMac. When I tried booting it, the loading bar went half way, slowed way down, then about 20-30 min later, the bar had gotten all the way to the end... But it stayed on the booting screen. So I forced shutdown my computer, then tried booting up it again. But it didn't even try to load. It just showed a blank white screen. No text what so ever. I tried many different methods to fix this, booting in safe mode, single user mode, reset nvram, recovery mode, etc. But every time I tried any of these methods, I would still get a blank white screen. I am at a loss. I can't even try to reinstall the OS if I wanted to since it only boots to this white screen. Does anyone know how what I can do to fix this? (I believe my computer is a 2010 iMac, if that helps)

Quick Update: I just tried booting it while pushing the power button + option button. Even though the screen is still completely white, now the mouse pointer has shown up on the screen and I am able to move it around. But not sure if that indicates something or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iMac doesn‘t start up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320914/imac-doesn-t-start-up)

Comment: @Allan I'd disagree that this is a possible duplication, because the question you link explains he can read something on the screen that points to a problem/error. But for me, there is no text what so ever. So this question is different in comparison to that question.

Comment: Loop chime? I meet a similar problem on macbook air. No logo, blank white screen, loop chime. And I found this:https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/120225/Looping+chime+on+booting As it said, flash Memory maybe corrupted. I can't fix it, hope you can find other way to fix it.

Comment: I've seen a white screen a few times. We had to let Apple repair those computers. It was a different hardware issue each time. — Although each time that happened the cursor was not visible. — I have seen a black screen with the cursor many times and that's not been quite as serious. Never seen a white screen with cursor, I don't think. — Did you try googling about white screen with cursor?

Comment: @Joonas well the curser only occurred when I try booting while holding down the option key. And I have not googled anything about it. Might be best to just take it to Apple to get it fixed. I just don’t want to pay quite a bit of money to find out it was only a $20 hardware issue.

Comment: @Allan doesn’t work. No text will appear. Just a completely white screen.

Comment: Try [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: @Allan Progress! But I don’t think it is good. Upon trying AHT, a flashing folder with a question mark appeared. This means that my computer can’t find it’s “system software”, I think. Apple recommends that if the computer does not boot, to try to enter recovery mode. But unfortunately, I can’t do that. I think I need to bring it into Apple to figure this out.

Comment: You don't need to take it in just yet.  I would try Internet Recovery (Command-Option-R) or if you have a friend that can create a USB installer for you, use that to boot.  If you're going to install, install it to an external drive (it's just for testing).  If it works there, it points to your drive as the failed component and we can move forward from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot up using Cmd + Option + P + R to reset the PRAM.

Also try booting up with Cmd + R for recovery mode.

It seems likely the main hard drive has failed.

If you can boot up into Cmd + option, you will be able to boot into a Boot CD or other recovery disc/USB drive to help restore your main hard drive.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried resetting the PRAM, entering recovery mode, and using cmd + option. They don’t work. The only that has that slightest affect is `cmd + option`. When I do that, I can move the mouse pointer on the screen. That is about it. So you of think that it is likely that the main HD has failed? Is there a way to confirm this? Maybe be connecting another computer to the iMac?