# How to fix memory corruption on 2011 MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, repair, hardware-recommendation, macos

I got a 2011 MacBook Air 13”, the device was slowly dying. Now it only boots intermittently and crashes/freezes within 15 seconds of boot up. Many times it does not boot at all - just black screen and 3 beeps followed by 5 second pause.

It appears to be memory (RAM) corruption, maybe; logic board corruption.

I think my hard drive is encrypted/password protected (asks for password when I boot with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>⦿ Pwr</kbd>

**How do I fix the logic board/ memory corruption on 2011 MacBook Air 13”**

I'm trying to determine the most economic way to fix my Mac, so I am looking at various options:

I can buy a working, used MacBook Air off ebay (~200$ on auction or 350$ buy now) and swap hard drive into that one using a set of specialized screwdrivers

-or-

I can buy a refurbished logic board for up to 250$ and pay a technician 100$ for an hour labor to swap it.

**Do I have other options?** I tried hard reset and reset NVRAM (which got the device to show login screen). As I log in, the screen gets progressively more corrupted - see screenshot.  Then, the Mac turns off shortly after.

If I buy a new device I would still have to pay for data recovery and transfer service, as the old device is non functional?

[image: MBA Corrupted Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You have several options to fix this issue:

1. Have the board [professionally repaired](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rTU0bLZROE).  This is a common repair that can be done, but it's not economically feasible because the cost of the labor is very high in comparison to what you can get a new MacBook Air for
2. Swap out the logic board for a known working one ([available on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2323012.m570.l1311.R2.TR2.TRC0.A0.H0.X2011%20macbook%20air%20logic.TRS0&_nkw=macbook%20air%2013%202011%20logic%20board&_sacat=0) for less than $200USD).  This may be a viable option, but keep in mind, your MBA is 8+ years old.  You will be expending money to get another 8 year old machine.
3. Buy a new machine and transfer your data using an [external enclosure](http://radnex.us/MBA_2010-2011_SSD_Enclosure).  The 2011 MBAs had a *removable* SSD that you could remove and put into a replacement machine or you could put it into a USB enclosure so you can extract your data.

Personally, I would buy a new MacBook, MacBook Air/Pro.  I would remove the SSD from the dead machine, put it into an enclosure to extract the data and then sell the 2011 MBA as salvage parts.

> If I buy a new device I would still have to pay for data recovery and
>   transfer service, as the old device is non functional

This is what Time Machine backups are for and [it's extremely cheap insurance](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320930/119271) in case of a failure (see the section titled  "A Word About Backing up Your Data").  That enclosure could then serve as a USB drive for future Time Machine backups.

Comment: I'm also confused as to the correct logic board for repair - I see that there are at least 3 different part numbers of the logic board listed on Ebay. Good points on getting an ancient machine - data transfer is probably the best option

Comment: There are 3 different PN"s because there was different CPU configurations (1.6GHz i5, 1.7GHz i5, and 1.8GHz i7).  I believe they all came with 4GB RAM as the max.  If it's a 2011 MBA logic board, it will fit.