# My iMac wont boot up

Tags: imac, startup

Need some help please, my iMac (A1224, OS X EL CAPITAN) wont boot up, for some reason <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> doesn't work, which leaves me with single user mode. I tried `fsck` but I'm getting the error below, I only have moderate IT skills so any help would be great.

[image]

Comment: iMac model?  Version of macOS you were using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iMac doesn‘t start up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320914/imac-doesn-t-start-up)

Comment: Its an A1224, OS X EL CAPITAN.

Comment: That needs to be in the question itself.  Remember, we can't look over your shoulder.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that.

Comment: Did you force restart your iMac and start-up without holding any keys down?

Comment: [A1224 covers a number of iMac models](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=A1224) which one specifically are you referring to?

Comment: Does internet recovery work with that OS?  If so, you should try it

Comment: Force restarted the mac, no joy. Can i use internet recovery through single user mode?

Comment: Based on the solution to a similar problem it sounds like the drive has failed. Can i at least delete my data off the drive? If so can someone give me a step by step guide please?