# Early 2008 iMac HD: diskmanagment .disenter error 49180 impossible to mount the disk

Tags: hard-drive

I'm pretty sure I'm not the first to reach out with this problem and I do not know if there is any solution other than change the disk. I appreciate any input you can provide and also I would like to know if there is any "bootable" usb solution able to format and mount the disk as with utility disk it is just impossible. Thanks in advance and Happy new year to everybody!

Comment: Is it the original drive that came with the Mac?

Comment: Yes absolutely all genuine, as a matter of fact I was trying to upgrade from El capitan to Catalina produced the USB Catalina installer from Catalina Patcher taken from DOSDUDE1 site and I've managed to install it although it showed some bugs so I've decided to perform the installation again and when I went to erase the disk it dismounted and never worked again. I can enter the OS recovery utilities using the USB Catalina installer but impossible to erase, format and mount again the hard disk which is the only one inside the machine. Your support is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It’s a spinning drive and the drive is now 16 years old.  It has failed and needs to be replaced  That vintage Mac could be easily serviced

Comment: Take a look at [this question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320914/119271).

Comment: Alan Thanks a lot I will look at the link and yes I was considering changing the drive although the sos check says that it appears to be ok.